# Bash - String Manipulation Minus Sign (-) (hyphen)

Tags: string, bash

While looking at the *apache* run script `/etc/init.d/apache2` I realise something different in [String Manipulating](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) for **Substring Extraction**. For example:

```
if [ "${APACHE_CONFDIR##/etc/apache2-}" != "${APACHE_CONFDIR}" ] ; then
```

or

```
if [ -n "${PIDTMP:-}" ] && kill -0 "${PIDTMP:-}" 2> /dev/null; then
```

The second one seems **Use Default Values** if `PIDTMP` is unset or null but I didn't find it logical in this one.

What is the use of minus sign (`-`) in each case? Brief explanation would be helpful.

*Note:I am interested in minus signs only in braces and I already checked `:-word` .*

Comment: Those two are different. The first one strips `/etc/apache2-` from the front of `$APACHE_CONFDIR`, the second one defaults to empty string, which seems to be pretty much useless (`"${PIDTMP}"` is the empty string when `PIDTMP` isn't set).

Comment: Sometimes redundant additions confuse people, but thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that this has no real effect. `:-` is supposed to mean: "if not set, use the following default value", but since nothing follows, afaik it has no effect:

- if the variable is set, then default value will NOT be taken
- if the variable is unset, the it will expand to "", which would have happened anyway when using `"${PIDTMP}"`.

The only use case I can imagine is to make sure that the expansion contains at least the empty string and not an "unset variable" (this makes a difference when the `-u` option is in effect).

In the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> ***${parameter:-word}*** Use Default Values. If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

and

> ***-u*** Treat unset variables and parameters other than the special parameters `"@"` and `"*"` as an error when performing parameter expansion. If expansion is attempted on an unset variable or parameter, the shell prints an error message, and, if not interactive, exits with a non-zero status.

Comment: Thank you. I would expecting logical answer, but it seems how it is. Maybe it is there for historical concerns.

Comment: yes, any script can have "historical leftovers" :)

Comment: the `-n` option of bash works also for unset parameters, so the script would do exactly the same if we removed the :- everywhere.

Comment: There is a difference between `${foo:-}` and `${foo}`, when bash option `-u` is set - the former is never an error.

Comment: @TobySpeight do you have any reference for this `bash -u` option? I think that might cover the case I described, where it matters for bash if a variable is unset or empty string.

Comment: @Chris - yes, that's the error-on-unset flag.  See the docs for `set` in the SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS section of the manual page.

Comment: `-u  Treat unset variables as an error when substituting.` so without `:-` gives error now as `bash: foo: unbound variable`. Thank you @TobySpeight